# Golang: client: dial: tls: oversized record received with length 20527

Tags: golang, tcp, request, tls, x509certificate

Пытаюсь отправить `TLS` запрос с `self signed certificate`, но получаю ошибку ввида: `client: dial: tls: oversized record received with length 20527`.
Вот сам код:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "math/big"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func CertTemplate() (*x509.Certificate, error) {
    serialNumberLimit := new(big.Int).Lsh(big.NewInt(1), 128)
    serialNumber, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, serialNumberLimit)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("failed to generate serial number: " + err.Error())
    }

    tmpl := x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber:          serialNumber,
        Subject:               pkix.Name{Organization: []string{"Yhat, Inc."}},
        SignatureAlgorithm:    x509.SHA256WithRSA,
        NotBefore:             time.Now(),
        NotAfter:              time.Now().Add(time.Hour),
        BasicConstraintsValid: true,
    }
    return &tmpl, nil
}

func CreateCert(template, parent *x509.Certificate, pub interface{}, parentPriv interface{}) (
    cert *x509.Certificate, certPEM []byte, err error) {

    certDER, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, template, parent, pub, parentPriv)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    cert, err = x509.ParseCertificate(certDER)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    b := pem.Block{Type: "CERTIFICATE", Bytes: certDER}
    certPEM = pem.EncodeToMemory(&b)
    return
}

func main() {
    rootKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("generating random key: %v", err)
    }

    rootCertTmpl, err := CertTemplate()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("creating cert template: %v", err)
    }
    rootCertTmpl.IsCA = true
    rootCertTmpl.KeyUsage = x509.KeyUsageCertSign | x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature
    rootCertTmpl.ExtKeyUsage = []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth, x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth}
    rootCertTmpl.IPAddresses = []net.IP{net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")}

    rootCert, rootCertPEM, err := CreateCert(rootCertTmpl, rootCertTmpl, &rootKey.PublicKey, rootKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error creating cert: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", rootCertPEM)
    fmt.Printf("%#x\n", rootCert.Signature) // more ugly binary

    /*rootKeyPEM := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{
        Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(rootKey),
    })*/

    // Create a TLS cert using the private key and certificate
    /*rootTLSCert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(rootCertPEM, rootKeyPEM)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("invalid key pair: %v", err)
    }*/

    ///
    //
    //
    //

    servKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("generating random key: %v", err)
    }

    servCertTmpl, err := CertTemplate()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("creating cert template: %v", err)
    }
    servCertTmpl.KeyUsage = x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature
    servCertTmpl.ExtKeyUsage = []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth}
    servCertTmpl.IPAddresses = []net.IP{net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")}

    _, servCertPEM, err := CreateCert(servCertTmpl, rootCert, &servKey.PublicKey, rootKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error creating cert: %v", err)
    }

    servKeyPEM := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{
        Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(servKey),
    })
    servTLSCert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(servCertPEM, servKeyPEM)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("invalid key pair: %v", err)
    }

    config := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{servTLSCert},
    }

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "google.com:80", config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("client: dial: %s", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    log.Println("client: connected to: ", conn.RemoteAddr())

    state := conn.ConnectionState()
    for _, v := range state.PeerCertificates {
        fmt.Println(x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(v.PublicKey))
        fmt.Println(v.Subject)
    }
    log.Println("client: handshake: ", state.HandshakeComplete)
    log.Println("client: mutual: ", state.NegotiatedProtocolIsMutual)

    message := "Hello\n"
    n, err := io.WriteString(conn, message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("client: write: %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("client: wrote %q (%d bytes)", message, n)

    reply := make([]byte, 256)
    n, err = conn.Read(reply)
    log.Printf("client: read %q (%d bytes)", string(reply[:n]), n)
    log.Print("client: exiting")

}
```

Не понимаю что делать и в чем все таки проблема, адрес даю гугловский для примера *google.com:80*

Comment: Эм. 80 порт -- это HTTP. У HTTPS порт 443.

Comment: @Ainar-G тьфу, точно, спасибо Вам, не заметил что 80 порт стоит :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По результатам обсуждения в комментариях, проблема в том, что вы стучитесь на HTTP-порт 80, в то время как с HTTPS (TLS) надо работать на порту 443.